# Conditional paste only if a value is not empty

Tags: r, conditional-statements, paste

I am trying to construct a markdown document and the text feed from a database.
I would like to construct a sentence with paste() only if name is not empty. Otherwise do not  construct.

```
paste("Hi", name)
```

is it possible without a loop and without throuwing errors?

To make clear, if `name` is empty, `Hi` should **not** be printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If empty means undefined then use either of these:

```
if (exists("name")) paste("Hi", name)

try(paste("Hi", name), silent = TRUE)
```

If we know it is defined but empty means it has zero characters:

```
if (nzchar(name)) paste("Hi", name)
```

If we only want to run paste if name is defined and has a non-zero number of characters then use any of these.  Note that && short circuits so if the left hand side of && is FALSE it will immediately return FALSE without attempting to evaluate the right hand side which is important since had it attempted that an error would have been generated.

```
if (exists("name") && nzchar(name)) paste("Hi", name)

try(if (nzchar(name)) paste("Hi", name), silent = TRUE)
```